# How to know what are in a file and what aren't in another?

Tags: linux, backup, diff, amazon-s3

I doing a `nrpe` check for my `nagios` about the files that I backup, sending to `Amazon S3`.
I have two files then, `s3`, which list all my files that are in Amazon already. And `local` which list all my files in my machine.
I need to know what is in `local` and not is in `s3`.
Example:

s3

```
2013-07-01 04:49       145   32ddd73694ab610c3f077a88fb9f3300  s3://company-backup/company-logs/file.1.gz
2013-07-01 04:57       145   68adf73694ab610c3f077a88fb9f3300  s3://company-backup/company-logs/file.2.gz
2013-07-01 05:12       145   36ede43644ab710c8f077a88fb9f3300  s3://company-backup/company-logs/file.3.gz
```

local

```
32ddd73694ab610c3f077a88fb9f3300  /company-logs/file.1.gz
68adf73694ab610c3f077a88fb9f3300  /company-logs/file.2.gz
36ede43644ab710c8f077a88fb9f3300  /company-logs/file.3.gz
72ede57455eb850c8f078a88fb9f5900  /company-logs/file.4.gz
```

Notice that `72ede57455eb850c8f078a88fb9f5900  /company-logs/file.4.gz` isn't in `s3` file.
And this is what should return to me, how can I do that ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one liner:

```
diff <(awk '{print $4}' s3 | sort) <(awk '{print $1}' local | sort)
```

Basically, what it does is compare the output of `awk`, which we'll use to print the fourth and first column of the files, respectively. We need to sort the output in case the hashes are in different orders. The `<(…)` syntax is process substitution and allows us to run `diff` on the output of two commands, while usually it'd only allow you to work with files.

It outputs:

```
<
---
> 72ede57455eb850c8f078a88fb9f5900
```

So you'll know `72ede57455eb850c8f078a88fb9f5900` is only in the "right" file, i.e. `local`.

Comment: That's some slick `awk` magic. :)

Comment: Heh, thanks. It beats `cut` in those cases where multiple spaces and not tabs (or other single delimiters) are used to separate columns (at least in terms of readability).